# How to get Max id in table column database?when id store as string?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my app i want to get max id from my column .am using Max function  get max id 0-9 ,,but after 10 its not work.

The reason is am store **id** datatype as **TEXT** not an **INT**.How to get max id from that id column for all vales?

Comment: id column stores only numbers(0-9) or alphanumeric(0-9 A-Z).

Comment: only numbers(0-9) but stored as string

Comment: Change your app to store the IDs as numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
SELECT max(CAST(id as int)) from TABLE_NAME
```

Using [Sqlite CAST](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html) you can do it. But it will be good if you choose integer for id column.